# For Loop for checking whether specific id is found in a array

Tags: ios, swift, loops, for-loop

I need to check the id in a array list , id has been generated previously and just I need to compare with the response generated later, For example: take "defaultcardid" is the previous generated id, so I need to compare the "defaultcard" with later response.

I am getting a "cardlist" as a "Anyobject" response. so need to check "defaultcardid" inside "cardlist" array.

```
if let xlist = (cardlist.value(forKey: "data")as? NSArray)
{
    for 0 .. i in xlist
    {
        cardfinder.adding((xlist.object(at: id)as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id")as! String)
    }
}
```

cardfinder is a NSMUTABLEARRAY to store the particular id into an array.

My son response is below

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "card_1D42hlLJSnYRR6BMULHyeobB",
        "object": "card",
        "address_city": null,
        "address_country": null,
        "address_line1": null,
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_state": null,
        "address_zip": null,
        "address_zip_check": null,
        "brand": "Visa",
        "country": "US",
        "customer": "cus_DV2VCweBfI1dH0",
        "cvc_check": "pass",
        "dynamic_last4": null,
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2019,
        "fingerprint": "FwLfSpHMDz1b3PTH",
        "funding": "debit",
        "last4": "5556",
        "metadata": {},
        "name": null,
        "tokenization_method": null
    },
    {
        "id": "card_1D441WLJSnYRR6BMNpOsFgg0",
        "object": "card",
        "address_city": null,
        "address_country": null,
        "address_line1": null,
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_state": null,
        "address_zip": null,
        "address_zip_check": null,
        "brand": "Visa",
        "country": "US",
        "customer": "cus_DV2VCweBfI1dH0",
        "cvc_check": "pass",
        "dynamic_last4": null,
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2019,
        "fingerprint": "dvLGAxROCikDisQx",
        "funding": "credit",
        "last4": "0093",
        "metadata": {},
        "name": null,
        "tokenization_method": null
    },
    {
        "id": "card_1D42RjLJSnYRR6BMgSELUUut",
        "object": "card",
        "address_city": null,
        "address_country": null,
        "address_line1": null,
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_state": null,
        "address_zip": null,
        "address_zip_check": null,
        "brand": "Visa",
        "country": "US",
        "customer": "cus_DV2VCweBfI1dH0",
        "cvc_check": "pass",
        "dynamic_last4": null,
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2019,
        "fingerprint": "NnWxCq6FamUKl226",
        "funding": "credit",
        "last4": "4242",
        "metadata": {},
        "name": null,
        "tokenization_method": null
    }
]
```

}

All the objects have field called "id" I already have a default id = card_1D42RjLJSnYRR6BMgSELUUut , I need to exactly take in which object my card is . 
so I need a for loop for checking all the objects in array.

Comment: Add an example of what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I am having a JSON response, in that response I need to check the value in key Called "id", if the value in key "id" is equal to what I have works fine, ignorer to check that my. son response has many array object. so need a for loop for going through all the object and check what I have

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` in Swift - use the native `Array` type

Comment: func gettingthedefaultcard()
    {
        let i = 0

        if let xlist = (cardlist.value(forKey: "data")as? NSArray)
        {
            for 0..i in xlist
            {
                cardfinder.append((xlist.object(at: i)as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id")as! String)
            }
        }

    }

Comment: @KARTHICKTM I suggest you use yourArray.contains()

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call **`contains`** method on `array` to check whether a value exist in it. Implementation depends upon the type of `array` you are checking.

**Example:**

Let's assume `"123" is the default id`.

```
var cardList1 = ["123", "abc", "xyz"]
cardList1.contains("123") //true
cardList1.contains("456") //false

var cardList2 = [["id": "123"], ["id": "abc"], ["id": "xyz"]]
cardList2.contains {                //true
    return $0["id"] == "123"
}
cardList2.contains {                //false
    return $0["id"] == "564"
}
```

Let me know in case you face any issue with this.

Comment: As per u r concern u are having a array called CardList1 na , I am trying to add data into the array using a for loop

Comment: I am already having a empty array called "cardfinder" where I am trying to add "id"  from the array object from my response.

Comment: Right. Then you must use the 2nd version of `contains` method i.e. `contains(where:)`. This method accepts a `closure` in which you can give any condition  as per your requirement.

Comment: After adding the data into array we can check it though contains

Comment: What is the use of `cardfinder` here?

Comment: u are having a array with details already, but I don't have data inside my array then how should I check

Comment: cardfinder is a array which I created to add the id field taken from the response

Comment: You must have an array in which you are adding all the elements from which you want to search the one with default id?

Comment: I will check with "i" objects inside the array from my response and I will save it inside the response

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.